Restriction of a vector bundle to a nodal curve
Let $S\to B$ be an elliptic surface with one nodal singular fiber C (a nodal projective curve $C$ of genus $g=1$). Let $\mathcal F$ be a slope-semistable rank-$2$ vector bundle on $S$.
What can we say about the restriction of $\mathcal F|_C$?

Is it locally free?
Is it torsion free?
Does it belong to $\operatorname{Ext}^1(L,\mathcal O_C)$ for some $L\in \operatorname{Pic}(C)$?

Many thanks for any help and references.
